# ngClass class change is slow when triggered from document-bound event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've build a dropdown menu element directive in Angular. ngClick on the menu button toggles the menu and works seamlessly. However, my `$document.click` binding to close the menu when a click happens outside it takes a few seconds to happen.

I've put a breakpoint on the binding and on my `closeMenu` scope function. Both of those happen immediately, but the class change that results from my ngClass attribute doesn't seem to change the element's class for another second or two.

In [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UPCnLhba75S2huNzFiT0ltLW8/edit?usp=sharing), I've demonstrated the two ways to close the dropdown: first, by clicking the dropdown button which fires a function via ngClick to change `menuActive` which turns the active class off. Second, by clicking outside the menu which fires `$document`'s click event to change the same scope variable as the first method. You can see the delay of about 2 seconds when not closing with the dropdown menu button.

Here's my directive:

```
angular.module('dropdownDirective', [])
    .directive('dropdown', function($document) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                ngIcon: '@',
                ngCaret: '@',
                ngLabel: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: '/gridsmart-web-client/directives/dropdown/dropdown.html',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                var handler = function(event) {
                    if (!element[0].contains(event.target)) {
                        scope.closeMenu();
                    }
                };

                $document.on('click', handler);
                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    $document.off('click', handler);
                });

                scope.clicked = false;
                scope.positionDropdown = function() {
                    if (!scope.clicked) {
                        scope.clicked = true;
                        scope.buttonHeight = element.find('button')[0].offsetHeight + 'px';
                    }
                };
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.menuActive = false;
                $scope.toggleMenu = function () {
                    $scope.positionDropdown();
                    $scope.menuActive = !$scope.menuActive;
                };
                $scope.closeMenu = function() {
                    $scope.menuActive = false;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

And here's the dropdown's template:

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-class="{active: menuActive}">
    <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">{{ngLabel}}<i ng-class="ngIcon" ng-if="ngIcon"></i><b class="caret" ng-if="ngCaret"></b></button>
    <ul ng-show="menuActive" ng-style="{'top': buttonHeight}" ng-transclude>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ngClick for the button simply toggles the value of `menuActive`. Since the `$document.click` binding manipulates the same variable, I can't imagine why the class change would be so much slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call `$apply()` in you event handler:

```
$document.on('click', function(event) {
    handler(event);
    scope.$apply();
});
```